# Showing error while passing json encoded associative array from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, moodle

I have an associative array after json_encode like this

```
{"1":"CourseA", "2":"CourseB"}
```

and it is stored in a php variable named $jsonObject.Now, I want to send this to a javascript function and use that array inside that function. The
function is invoked onclick like this:

```
 <a href="#" onclick="popup('.$jsonObject.');">link</a>
```

The problem is: It shows an error:invalid id popup({....

Whats the reason and what should be the solution for that? btw, I am working in moodle and the above link is shown inside a moodle block and declared inside $this->content->text.

Comment: Just leave it as JSON and html encode it into the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html encode the JSON to escape special characters,

```
<a href="#" onclick="popup('.htmlspecialchars($jsonObject).');">link</a>
```